# How to mask a string based on a pattern of string of same length

Tags: r, string

I have the following set of string:

```
core_string     <- "AFFVQTCRE"
mask_string     <- "*KKKKKKKK"
```

What I want to do is to mask `core_string` with `mask_string`.
Whenever the `*` coincide with character in `core_string`, we will keep that character,
otherwise replace it.

So the desired result is:

```
   AKKKKKKKK
```

Other example

```
core_string     <- "AFFVQTCRE"
mask_string     <- "*KKKK*KKK"
 #     result       AKKKKTKKK
```

The length of both strings is always the same.
How can I do that with R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a helper function that will do just that

```
apply_mask <- function(x, mask) {
  unlist(Map(function(z, m) {
    m[m=="*"]  <- z[m=="*"]
    paste(m, collapse="")
  }, strsplit(x, ""), strsplit(mask, "")))
}
```

basically you just split up the string into characters and replace the characters that have a "*" then paste the strings back together.

I used the `Map` to make sure the function is still vectorized over the inputs. For example

```
core_string     <- c("AFFVQTCRE", "ABCDEFGHI")
mask_string     <- "*KKKK*KKK"

apply_mask(core_string, mask_string)
# [1] "AKKKKTKKK" "AKKKKFKKK"
```

Answer (score 2):

`regmatches` in replacement form `<-` can be handy here:

```
regmatches(core_string, gregexpr("K", mask_string)) <- "K"
core_string
#[1] "AKKKKKKKK"
```

If it's a 1:1 match of characters rather than a constant, then it has to be changed up a little:

```
ss <- strsplit(mask_string, "")[[1]]
regmatches(core_string, gregexpr("[^*]", mask_string)) <- ss[ss != "*"]
```